# Iterate over bean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, jstl

We normally do something like this JSTL on the jsp....but I now need to set data in the javascript using JSON.  How would I do something like this in Javascript/JSON

Basically loop over a bean and pull out its parameters:

```
  <c:forEach var="field" items="${detFields}">
      ${field.groupName}
          ${field.breakoutAllowed}           
 </c:forEach>
```

so I can put it inside something like this:

```
    "data": [{
        "value": "${field.groupName}"

    }, {

        "value": "${field.breakoutAllowed}"  
    }]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the JSON structure you're looking for is an array of objects, each with two properties: `name` and `breakoutAllowed`. JavaScript to assign this data to a variable could be output like this from a JSP file. (Within a `<script>` block or equivalent, of course.)

```
var output = [
 <c:forEach var="field" items="${detFields}" varStatus="status">
   { 
     "name":"${field.groupName}",
     "breakoutAllowed":"${field.breakoutAllowed}" 
   }
   <c:if test="${not status.last}">,</c:if>
 </c:forEach>
]
```

Comment: I guess this cannot be written in the middle of a JSP file since the entire thing is a JavaScript ? We can store the values in a parameter of string type and then reference them using JQuery and then splitting as a JSON... Am I a bit misguided?

Comment: @ShivKumarGanesh Yeah, this would go in a JSP but I was a bit unclear about the whole thing I guess. Hope the edit clarifies things a bit.

Comment: +1 Now that outputs a perfect array!!! But I would still give another solution. Just let me know if it looks fine to you.

Comment: So I can write java cde right into the javascript like that??

Comment: Im going to give this a try fellas

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code works well and is liked by you. I consider writing scriptlet into JS a kinda weird practice so just suggested another way of approaching it. Please comment if necessary.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var k=$('#data').val();

    //Convert the value into the required array. Since writing it is JavaScript directly is not a daily practice.
    })

    <input type="hidden" id="data" value=
     <c:forEach var="field" items="${detFields}" varStatus="status">
       { 
         "name":"${field.groupName}",
         "breakoutAllowed":"${field.breakoutAllowed}" 
       }
       <c:if test="${not status.last}">,</c:if>
     </c:forEach>

     />
```